# Get whole week from date

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to find all the dates that would form a whole week based on a single date.

So if the date is located in the middle of the week like a Wednesday, it would return Sunday, Monday, up to Saturday.

Here's an example:

So let's say I have **Wed 10 Oct 2012**.

I would pass this date object to the function and the function would return `['2012-10-07', '2012-10-08', '2012-10-09', '2012-10-10', '2012-10-11', '2012-10-12', '2012-10-13']` (I don't want strings, but Date objects, strings are there just for the example ^^

I already tried myself, but the method I created is very long and dumb, here it is anyways: https://gist.github.com/3889121

But what I'm primarly looking for here is instructions. What to use, is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function that returns an Array of Date instances from the first sunday before the given date until the next sunday:

```
function getWeek(fromDate){
 var sunday = new Date(fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate()-fromDate.getDay()))
    ,result = [new Date(sunday)];
 while (sunday.setDate(sunday.getDate()+1) && sunday.getDay()!==0) {
  result.push(new Date(sunday));
 }
 return result;
}
// usage
var week = getWeek(new Date('2012/10/10'));
console.log(week[0]); //=> Sun Oct 07 2012 00:00:00
console.log(week[6]); //=> Sat Oct 13 2012 00:00:00
```

Just for fun, a shorter version (a oneliner) using `Array.map`, as an extension of the `Date.prototype`

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function(){
 return [new Date(this.setDate(this.getDate()-this.getDay()))]
          .concat(
            String(Array(6)).split(',')
               .map ( function(){
                       return new Date(this.setDate(this.getDate()+1));
                     }, this )
          );
}
// usage 
new Date('2012/10/10').getWeek(); //=> [07/10/2012, ... ,13/10/2012]
```

Comment: Very nice! Exactly what I was looking for! And it works flawlessly! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. I shortened the function a bit (no need for a nested function anymore).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 var date = new Date('2012/06/25');
 var day = date.getDay();
 var array = []
 for(var i=0;i<7;i++){
    if(i-day!=0){
      var days = i-day;
      var newDate =   new Date(date.getTime()+(days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      array.push(newDate);
 }
    else 
    array.push(date);
 }
 alert(array);​
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sazn8/)**

Comment: The code doesn't work, there's parentheses missing. I'll try playing with it to figure what's wrong with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Date.js library http://www.datejs.com
You can just do

```
someDate.next().sunday()
```

Comment: I needed a JS only way of doing it, I don't want to use third party libraries for this, sorry and thanks anyway!

Answer (score -1):

This may help you, you can enter in the yeat:int, month:int, and day:int, it will find the nearest last sunday then add 7 days. Lastly it will return a date range. You may need to modify the output to suit your needs. If your month int array goes from 1 to 12, leave the _monthint - 1 otherwise you can remove it.

```
var moment = require('moment');

let getDatesSundayTo7DaysAheadFromADay = function( _yearint, _monthint, _dayint ){
    var input = new Date(_yearint, _monthint - 1, _dayint)
    let getLastSunday = function (d) {
        var t = new Date(d);
        t.setDate(t.getDate() - t.getDay());
        return t;
      }
    let lastsunday = getLastSunday(input)
    let addDays = function(dateObj, numDays) {
        var newdate = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dateObj));
        for(var i = 1; i < numDays ; i++){
            newdate =  moment(newdate).add(1, 'days')
        }
        return newdate
      }
    let sevendaysahead = addDays(lastsunday, 7)
    function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
        var dateArray = [];
        var currentDate = moment(startDate);
        var stopDate = moment(stopDate);
        while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
            dateArray.push( moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') )
            currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
        }
        return dateArray;
    }
    return getDates(lastsunday, sevendaysahead);
}
```